# sending data from python to php using post/get requests

Tags: php, python, post, get

i need to send this file path `/Users/bob/Documents/python_stuff/venv/json_output.json` to the php page of `http://localhost:8888/demo/display_data.php`

My python code:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8888/demo/display_data.php'
file_path_json = {"1": "/Users/bob/Documents/python_stuff/venv/json_output.json"}
resp = requests.post(url, params=file_path_json)
```

php code:

```
$json_path['1'] = $_GET['1'];
```

I do not know why it is not working. I have installed the requests module.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried following code on my PC and it's working for me

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost/dx/index.php'
file_path_json = {"1": "/Users/bob/Documents/python_stuff/venv/json_output.json"}
resp = requests.post(url, file_path_json)
print(resp)
```

hope this helps

Comment: you just need to remove "params" just pass url and file_path_json into post request